# Reading from file vs generating data (speedwise)

Tags: c++, performance, file, input, abstract-data-type

> I'm writing a program in C++ that needs to generate a set of points in the xyz coordinate plane.  The set of points varies depending on a number x.  The first set has the point (0,0,0).  The second set has (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1).  The third set is contains the second set and adds the points (2,0,0), (2,1,0), (2,1,1), (2,2,0), (2,2,1), (2,2,2).

So I can actually generate the sets with 3 for loops, without much trouble.  However I need to use this set in a loop where I give it an input of x, and it needs to stores the set (into an ADT structure) according to the x, eg. if x =2 then the set that it will store is the second set mentioned above.

After each run of this, I process the data, and then the program starts over again and has to pull some another set from the same construction based on some other set of data that it processes before looking at the loop.

The size of the set is governed by the equation: (2x<sup>3</sup>+6x<sup>2</sup>+4x)/12 so the set grows semi-rapidly I guess.

**I was curious about whether** or not it's faster to generate this set, print it to a file, and then instead of regenerating the set every time, I read it in from the file I generated and store it into the ADT structure.  I actually need to run data from `x = 1`, to `x = 1000`, so no matter what I do, this portion of my program has to be run 1000 times.  Or should I not worry about this kind of things?

### Note:

I realized that I haven't given quite enough information.  This set of points, actually will be stored into a **doubly linked list**<sup>1</sup> because what I'm doing is that taking another set of points in 3 space, say `{point1, point2, ... }`.  I take `point1`, and I need to find the minimum distance of `point1` to every point in the generated set.  After that I have to remove the point that was in the generated set that had the minimum distance with `point1`.  Then I go on to `point2` and continue the process, until I have finished exhausting all the points in my other set.

As mentioned earlier, I'm going to be running for `x = 1`, to `x = 1000`, that means that I'm actually comparing 1001 different sets, to the n<sup>th</sup> set generated above.  I don't actually know which set I'll want to use from the generated set before hand, I'll only know which set I need to use during run time because the other set I'm using can only be put together during run time.  So I make an assessment on my size of that set, and get the x<sup>th</sup> set that is closest in size and do the minimum distance calculations stated above.

---

<sup>1. A friend of mine had mentioned that I could use an array as opposed to a doubly linked list, but the reason why I chose the doubly linked list is because I need to actually remove a point from my generated set with every minimum distance comparison (I may actually end up with an empty list when I finish doing the minimum distance comparisons).</sup>

Comment: Sounds like something that might be a good use of memcache or a ramdisk.

Comment: It will be much faster to generate it than read it from a file, even with a SSD drive. If there is any way to determine the size of the array up front, even if you have to resize it a few times, the array is preferable to a linked list. An array is a linked list where all the links are positioned right next to each other, in order, and then all the links are discarded. Your Q reminds me of Mark Twain's apology. "Sorry for the long letter. I didn't have time to write a short one." You obviously haven't spent enough time analyzing the problem, so this is going to waste everyone's time.

Comment: You definitely want to generate everything on the fly when it's just loop-counters.  Even a square-root lookup table might be best computed on the fly.  It's only when each individual value is really expensive compared to its storage space that loading a table from disk (e.g. baked into the executable) makes sense.  In this case, don't even generate a table first: generate each element on the fly when you want it.  Memory is slow, CPU is fast.  It's worth doing something clever with combinatorials to map a scalar integer to a tuple in 3-space to avoid storing them all.

Comment: Or of course for this specific problem of finding the nearest point, optimizing that a *lot* more than a brute-force search.  The nearest integer (x,y,z) for a given (a,b,c) is going to be one of the eight vertices of the 1x1x1 cube containing it.  A linked list sounds like a terrible idea, when you could get the same result with less bookkeeping with an array + metadata.